# python package for finding numerical solutions for equations with no-closed form solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have an equation of the form [image]

only r^* is unkown, is there any python package that can help me find a numerical solution of it?

Comment: The answer is already in your tags: `numpy` and `scipy`.

Answer (score 0):

Scipy has root-finding in the optimize subpackage. Try `scipy.optimize.root`